# How many mails can i send through nodemailer with express?

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer

I am recently using nodemailer for sending emails to all students in our college. But exactly I don't know how many emails can I send through the system. Now, successfully work by sending multiple emails and fetching the email from our Db. My one and the only question being how long and how many emails can I send through the system? 
Anyone know to tell me about it.

Thanks for Advance your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many as you want as long as your queueing system handles it the right way. 
Here is more information about how to handle a large amount of mails : https://community.nodemailer.com/delivering-bulk-mail/

Comment: and one more doubt how many individual mails can i send through nodemailer? I think Gmail provides 500 emails/per day so by this is it right or not?

Comment: Of course I assumed you have a proper SMTP system that allows so many mails. I am not sure a free mailer as gmail or yahoo will allow you to send everyday thousands of mails in a short amount of time…

Comment: now I am littele bit understand thanks for your help !